# RegExp ignore opening characters if next closing not found

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation

Is there a way how RegExp ignores a match if contains certain characters? I look around and found negative matches which works fine for certain cases `(?!\<)`. But I can't find a way how to create a negative match with optional any character until next opening bracket found. I Apologies for poor explanation. Here is an example which makes make more sense I guess.

```
const text = "hello <friend>. My age is < twenty <unit>.>Signature<<signature>."
const matches = text.split(/(\<(?!\<).*?\>)/g)
// ["hello ", "<friend>", ". My age is ", "< twenty <unit>", ".>Signature<", "<signature>", "."]
```

The Problem is `"< twenty <unit>"`. What I really looking for is two elements from value `"< twenty ", "<unit>"`

Comment: You may use `.split(/(<[^<>]*>?)/).filter(Boolean)`, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

make the negative lookahead `(?!)` part of the `.` match.
`/(<((?!<)[^>])*>)/`

This way every time `*` the dot is matched it has to comply with the look.

A lookahead works better than a lookbehind since the character you care about not matching is the next character, not the previous.

Also, replacing the anything match `.` with `[^>]` = `everything except closing tag` prevents overshooting the closing tag.

Instead of the lookahead you could also rewrite it to `/(<[^><]*>)/`, = `match everything between opening and closing tag that does not contain any tag`

I just reread your question. If I understand it correctly and you want to match the outer tag too, until the start of the inner tag, you can use this. It matches opening `<` + any non-tag + closing `>` if it exists

```
<[^><]*>?
```

Comment: You do not have a lookbehind in your pattern,  `(?!...)` is a negative lookahead.

Comment: yes, I just copied that from the question without looking, `(?<!...)` would be the negative lookahead, but it is not needed here. thanks!